# Haskell Recursion: interleave function in Programming in Haskell ch.11

Tags: haskell, recursion

I cannot figure out how the recursive mechanism for the following 'interleave' function in Programming in Haskell Ch.11 works.

```
-- Definition
interleave :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
interleave a [] = [[a]]
interleave x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys):map (y:) (interleave x ys)

-- Example
> interleave 3 [4,5,6,7]
[[3,4,5,6,7],[4,3,5,6,7],[4,5,3,6,7],[4,5,6,3,7],[4,5,6,7,3]]
```

How does it work under the hood?

I am stuck at reasoning like this:

```
interleave 3 [4,5,6,7]
= [3,4,5,6,7]:map (4:) (interleave 3 [5,6,7])
= [3,4,5,6,7]:[4,3,5,6,7]:map (5:) (interleave 3 [6,7])
= [3,4,5,6,7]:[4,3,5,6,7]:[5,3,6,7]:map (6:) (interleave 3 [7])
= [3,4,5,6,7]:[4,3,5,6,7]:[5,3,6,7]:[6,3,7]:map (7:) (interleave 3 [])
= [3,4,5,6,7]:[4,3,5,6,7]:[5,3,6,7]:[6,3,7]:[7,3]:[[3]]

= [[3,4,5,6,7],[4,3,5,6,7],[5,3,6,7],[6,3,7],[7,3],[3]]
???
/= [[3,4,5,6,7],[4,3,5,6,7],[4,5,3,6,7],[4,5,6,3,7],[4,5,6,7,3]]
```

Please enlighten me.. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the code used to define the `interleave` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between lines two and three you miss something:

```haskell
[3,4,5,6,7]:map (4:) (interleave 3 [5,6,7])
= [3,4,5,6,7]:map (4:) ([3,5,6,7]:map (5:) (interleave 3 [6,7]))
= [3,4,5,6,7]:[4,3,5,6,7]:map (4:) (map (5:) (interleave 3 [6,7]))
```

So at the end you have a bunch of `map (x:)` and all all lists contain all the elements of the original list